# AirPrint over VPN

Tags: ios, vpn, bonjour, airprint, dns

I have AirPrint-compatible printer, and it works fine in my local network. Also I have a VPN (OpenVPN, TUN mode) server on my local network running on a Raspberry Pi. If I connect to my local network through the VPN I can access local resources, like shared disks, but AirPrint printer does not show up.

How can I connect to my printer over VPN?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've spend quite a bit of time by trying to proxy Bonjour traffic over VPN, but in the end the Bonjour/mDNS traffic could be sent only over the TAP VPN, which is not supported by iOS.

But you can manually (by IP, not via Bonjour autodiscovery) add printer to iOS. This option is available only via configuration management:

1. Download `Apple Configurator 2` from the Mac AppStore
2. Connect your iOS device
3. Create `New Profile`
4. Choose `AirPrint` and fill in your printer configuration.
5. Save this profile
6. Select your device, press `Add`->`Profile` and install the profile you've just created
7. Now your iOS device would check for the printer's IP directly, bypassing AirPrint's autodiscovery. This method would work via VPN or when you are directly connected to a local network

Answer (score -2):

I use Tailscale VPN on a 5G connection was able to print to local network printer at home using Bonjour.

Comment: Does your setup include the raspberry pie as mentioned in the question? A little more detail would help everyone evaluate if this even addresses the question.